# Need to correct this UI table with php

Tags: php

I am trying to make a nice looking UI for my script with table text so it's more easy to look at it but if all of the data is not the same then it's not aligned properly. Is it possible to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$array = array("Test 4:Test 22222", "Test 673633:Test 9383838383");

echo "______________________________________________________________\n";
foreach ($array as $arr){
$split = explode(":",$arr);
echo "| $split[0]          |         $split[1]    |\n";
echo "______________________________________________________________\n";
}

?>
```

The result I get:......

```
______________________________________________________________
| Test 4          |         Test 22222    |
______________________________________________________________
| Test 673633          |         Test 9383838383    |
______________________________________________________________
```

The result I want:

```
______________________________________________________________
| Test 4               |         Test 22222         |
______________________________________________________________
| Test 673633          |         Test 9383838383    |
______________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Take a look at [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) and do some calculations

Comment: Here's an example to get you started: https://eval.in/425731

Comment: Additionally use a font with same-width chars. If you use ```<pre>text</pre>``` your browser will probably apply a font of that type.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this by simple text, Instead do it using some html and css to it like

```
    <?php
    $array = array("Test 4:Test 22222", "Test 673633:Test 9383838383");
    foreach ($array as $arr){
    $split = explode(":",$arr);
    echo "<label class='key'>$split[0]</label><label class='value'>$split[1]</label><br/>";
    }
```

CSS

```
    .key {
        border: 1px solid grey;
        width: 120px;
    }
    .value {
        border: 1px solid grey;
        width: 300px;
    }
```

And then you can add style to the classes `Key` and `value` to have borders around them and add a fix width to both of them 
        
        .key{border:1px solid grey;width:120px}
        .value{border:1px solid grey;width:300px}

Answer (score 0):

Using [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php), just toy around with the distance. Distance is set to 20 for now, so it will fill up the line until it has reached this distance with a character of your choosing

```
<?php
$array = array("Test 4:Test 22222", "Test 673633:Test 9383838383");
$distance = 20;
echo "______________________________________________________________\n";
foreach ($array as $arr){
 $split = explode(":",$arr);
 echo "|  ".str_pad($split[0], $distance, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT)."|  ".str_pad($split[1], $distance, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT)."|\n";
 echo "______________________________________________________________\n";
}

?>
```